# Run Python Script via VBA from different Computers

Tags: python, excel, vba

I want to develop a tool where it is necessary to start a Python script via VBA.

I found the following code on the internet:

```vb
Sub RunPythonScript() '''This sub starts the Python script that creates the plots

    Dim objShell As Object
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Dim PythonExePath, PythonScriptPath As String

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
    'PythonExePath = """C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe""" ' 
    PythonScriptPath = "C:\Projects\MYproject\cttdb_plot_creator.py" 
    
    objShell.Run PythonExePath & PythonScriptPath

End Sub
```

This code works for me. However, when a colleague starts the tool from his computer, it does not work.

I think that I have entered too specific a path for "PythonExePath", namely: `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe`.

Is there a way to enter a path that is more general and works for every user?

Comment: Look up the Where command for windows command line.

Comment: Hey, freeflow. Thank you for your comment. But i'm new in coding.....what do you mean with your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply have all users include the `python.exe` installation folder in their `Path` environment variable. On Windows which may require admin access, follow:

```
Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings 
 > Environment Variables... > Path > OK > [Add new folder where python.exe resides]
```

See screenshot dialogs:

[image: Windows Environment Path Dialogs]

Verify with PowerShell (`$Env:Path`) or CMD Prompt (`echo %Path%`).

Once done, you can shorten your command line with:

```vb
PythonExePath = "python"
PythonScriptPath = "C:\Projects\MYproject\cttdb_plot_creator.py" 
    
objShell.Run PythonExePath & " " & PythonScriptPath
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the solution. I will mark as correct answer.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! I hope screenshots help future readers as simply saying *add python to environment Path variable* may be formidable for newcomers.